# Creating a shortcut of the running script and making link executable in PowerShell console

Tags: powershell-2.0, shortcut-file

Then saving the link in C:\Users\Public\Desktop for easy access.

How do I go about doing this?

Basically the original PowerShell script will have to create a shortcut link to itself and save it in Public\Desktop folder and has to be executable in PowerShell once clicked (not open in notepad)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to run it in an elevated console :

```
"greetings from PS !"

$mypath=$MyInvocation.myCommand.definition
$app="%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\autogenerated.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $app
$Shortcut.Arguments ="-noexit -file $mypath"
$Shortcut.Description ="autogenerated shortcut from ps"
$Shortcut.Save()
```

Comment: Thank you!! This worked wonderfully, and breaking down the code and investigating how it worked was also a learning experience.

Comment: I'm glad this has helped you